# Может ли byte[] == null в Java?

Tags: java

И вообще корректно ли

```
private void myMethod(byte[] bs){
    if (bs != null){
       ... some code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Может, массивы - это данные ссылочного типа.

Answer (score 10):

Есть восемь типов данных, поддерживаемых Java. Основные типы данных предопределены языком и названы по ключевому слову. К ним относятся:

- **byte**

  Тип данных `byte` является 8-разрядным знаковым целым числом.

  Минимальная величина равна -128 (-2<sup>7</sup>)
  Максимальное значение равно +127 (включительно) (2<sup>7</sup>-1)

  По умолчанию – 0
- **short**

  Тип данных `short` является 16-разрядным знаковым целым числом.

  Минимальное значение равно -32 768 (-2<sup>15</sup>).
  Максимальная величина равна 32 767 (включительно) (2<sup>15</sup>-1).

  По умолчанию — 0.
- **int**

  В языке Java тип данных `int` является 32-разрядным знаковым целым числом.

  Минимальный размер int -2 147 483 648 (-2<sup>31</sup>).

  Максимальная величина равна +2 147 483 647 (включительно)(2<sup>31</sup>-1).
  .

  По умолчанию равно 0.
- **long**

  Тип данных `long` является 64-разрядным знаковым целым числом.

  Минимальное значение равно -9 223 372 036 854 775 808 (-2<sup>63</sup>).

  Максимальная величина +9 223 372 036 854 775 807 (включительно). (2<sup>63</sup>-1).

  По умолчанию — 0L.
- **float**

  Тип данных `float` является c одинарной точностью 32-битный IEEE 754 с плавающей точкой.

  По умолчанию — 0.0f.
- **double**

  Тип данных `double` является c двойной точностью 64-битный IEEE 754 с плавающей точкой..

  По умолчанию — 0.0d.
- **boolean**

  Тип данных `boolean` представляет собой один бит информации.

  Существует только два возможных значения: `true` и `false`.

  По умолчанию — `false`.
- **char**

  Тип данных `char` является одним 16-разрядным символом Юникода.

  Минимальная величина равна «\u0000» (или 0).

  Максимальная величина равна «\uffff» (или 65535 включительно).

  По умолчанию - 0

У каждого примитивного типа есть значение по умолчанию. Все остальное в Java это ссылочные типы данных(в том числе и массивы) и все они могут быть `null`

Answer (score 9):

Значение `byte` не может быть равным `null`, т. к. это [примитивный тип данных](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

[Массив](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) `byte[]` может (!!) быть равным `null`, т. к. это *объект*.

---

<sub>[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)</sub>

<sub>[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)</sub>

---

Ошибки нет:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bs = null;

    myMethod(bs);
    myMethod(null);
}

private static void myMethod(byte[] bs) {
    if (bs != null) {
        System.out.println("not null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
null
null
```

---

А в таком случае будет ошибка компиляции, т. к. переменная не инициализирована:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bs;
    myMethod(bs); // variable bs might not have been initialized
}
```